# log IP with php

Tags: php

I found this script online:

```
<?php

$v_ip = $REMOTE_ADDR;
$v_date = date("l d F H:i:s");

$fp = fopen("ips.txt", "a");
fputs($fp, "IP: $v_ip - DATE: $v_date\n\n");
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Creating the entry works. However, the IP is not displayed. The entries created look like this:

```
IP:  - DATE: Wednesday 09 March 03:36:15

IP:  - DATE: Wednesday 09 March 03:36:41
```

What's the problem?

Comment: @Mat: Welcome to CodeReview.SE.  This site is for reviewing working code.  This question is probably better for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 12):

The `$REMOTE_ADDR` variable will work only if you have `register_globals` turned on.
Normally you should use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

[PHP $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: You should always use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, even if `register_globals` is on.

Comment: This answer is right, but I'd recommend not to use register_globals.